# OpenVPN connects to local network but doesn't route back into the internet

Tags: routing, openvpn

A friend of mine has a raspberry at home with an OpenVPN server installed on it. He can access his local network (printer, wifi settings etc.) via the VPN from the internet. But for some reason it's not possible for him to get routed back into it. Here's the **local OpenVPN config-file**:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote <server ip> 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
tls-version-min 1.2
verify-x509-name server_MrmH0gFjOV3xl3NZ name
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
auth-nocache
verb 3
<public keys...>
```

The local network is 192.168.0.x/24 and the VPN-subnet is 10.8.0.x/24. If you need any more details we haven't thought about yet to help us, please let us know.

Edit (Added routing table and server-config):

**routing-table** [**route -n**]

```
Target          Router          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

**open vpn serverconfig**:

```
dev tun
proto udp
port 1194
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/issued/server_xxxxxx.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/private/server_xxxxxx.key
dh none
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
# Set your primary domain name server address for clients
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.222.222"
push "dhcp-option DNS 208.67.220.220"
# Prevent DNS leaks on Windows
push "block-outside-dns"
# Override the Client default gateway by using 0.0.0.0/1 and
# 128.0.0.0/1 rather than 0.0.0.0/0. This has the benefit of
# overriding but not wiping out the original default gateway.
push "redirect-gateway def1"
client-to-client
keepalive 1800 3600
remote-cert-tls client
tls-version-min 1.2
tls-crypt /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/pki/ta.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA256
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
crl-verify /etc/openvpn/crl.pem
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log 20
status-version 3
syslog
verb 3
#DuplicateCNs allow access control on a less-granular, per user basis.
#Remove # if you will manage access by user instead of device. 
#duplicate-cn
# Generated for use by PiVPN.io
```

Comment: Your question is entirely unclear.  If he can access stuff across the Internet through the VPN, obviously can "get routed back into it".  There is likely some issue with netmasks, networks and NAT, and more then likely the default gateway is not being pushed.  You may want to publish both client and server side configs (with password/credentials removed), and also provide the route table list for each system.

Comment: I've added them now. What do you mean with pushing the default gateway? Do I maybe have to add a route from the 198.168 network to the 10.8 one?

Comment: Please add the CLIENT route table. Also, can you provide a traceroute to something outside the network (eg 8.8.8.8) from client when VPN is up. Most importantly please provide output of "iptables -t nat -vnL" on the server. I expect the problem is either NAT related, but it could be something else.